# the error "mismatched input '@' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}" while using SQL query in SQLContext.sql

Tags: sql, pyspark

As title mentioned, when I tried like this

```
Email = '123456@gmail.com'
datanum = '3'

sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table WHERE E-mail = "+Email+" order by record date DESC Limit "+datanum).show()
```

it shows the error: mismatched input '@' expecting {, ';'}

However when I tried the following

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table WHERE E-mail = 123456@gmail.com order by record date DESC Limit 3").show()
```

everything works fine. Why? I prefer the above one, and have no idea to make it work. Please share your ideas with me, I'll be very appreciate.

Comment: oh... both E-mail and record date are like this: `E-mail`, `record date`, the above are just typo error.

Comment: Now I see... Anyway, use straight quotes for string literals, like `'123456@gmail.com'`.

Comment: You should use parameters instead of string substitution. SQL injection...

Comment: @jarlh I do use the straight quotes.

Comment: @jarlh I tried 
    
    @ Email and @ datanum 

but it seems not working. Not sure what you mean "use parameters" could you share an example? Thanks.

Comment: @jarlh OH! I think I got what you mean and make it works. Thanks a lot.